# Instance of class and function return type confusion

Tags: c++, class, function-prototypes

I cannot do this:

```
class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
    }

};

A a1();
```

Because `A a1();` looks like a function prototype.

But I can do this:

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(std::string argument)
    {
        std::cout << argument;
    }
};

B b1("Text");
```

These two things are essentially the same except the compiler is able to distinguish  `B b1("Text");` as NOT being a function prototype, because some data is passed in the parenthesis.

Is there any reason why the brackets must be omitted for A, or is the reason because the compiler thinks it is a function definition?

Comment: This is called the _most vexing parse_, and it has already been covered very well on Stack Overflow. Please see the linked duplicate, and the "Related" sidebar to your right.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly it, and it's known as **most vexing parse**. The reason is that if `A a1();` was treated as an object declaration, you wouldn't be able to declare a function with that prototype. And you want to be able to declare a function, right?

`B b1("Text");` works because it can't be treated as a function prototype, but, for example, `B b(A());` can and will.

Comment: Isn't this a vexing parse but not the *most* vexing?

Comment: +1 I wouldn't usually upvote an answer on an obvious duplicate, but your first paragraph is _that_ good :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it wasn't formulated as most, that's why I answered (I've been laying of the obvious ones recently).